# Jquery slide toggle from left to right like facebook app

Tags: jquery, toggle, slide

I have the below code which seems to work ok but does not seem to slide in when the trigger is first selected.  Its slides in and out nicely once it has been triggered but on the very first trigger it simply shows instead of sliding into view.

```
var $trigger = $(".icon-menu-2");
var $menu = $(".c_left");
$trigger.toggle(function show() {
  $menu.animate({
    width: 185,
    marginLeft: 0,
    display: 'toggle'
  }, 'slow');
}, function hide() {
  $menu.animate({
    width: 0,
    marginLeft: -185,
    display: 'toggle'
  }, 'slow');
});
```

It would also be nice if I could somehow get the whole page move to the right as facebook apps work.  Any ideas on how to achieve this?  I have looked into using jPanelmenu but this does not work with my code for various reasons and wondered if there was a simple solution to add to the above code.

many thanks in advance

Comment: Is your code wrapped in a document ready call?

Comment: yes it is, just didn't post that bit.

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DvbDf/

Comment: no it just appears, I have made a box to show you more clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/DvbDf/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.c_left {
    margin-left: -185px;
    width:0;
}
```

Updated fiddle by Arun P Johny http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/DvbDf/2/

Comment: don't suppose you know the answer to the 2nd part of the question, re: getting right side to slide over also like facebook.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by that? Facebook just uses a different CSS for it's app pages as far as I can tell.

Comment: am wanting to get the right panel to slide over to the right as the left panel slides out instead of going underneath the right div.  Please see amendment to illustrate http://jsfiddle.net/DvbDf/7/